# SharedPreferences настройки приложения

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Как организовать в настройках приложения функцию скрыть/показать textview.
Пытался с помощью SharedPreferences, но так и понял.

Как вписывать в файл настроек?
Как читать из файла?

Файл настроек:

```
public class setting1 extends PreferenceFragment {


public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_notification);
}


}
```

xml:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<SwitchPreference
    android:key="hidetext"
    android:summaryOff="Перевод выключен"
    android:summaryOn="Перевод включен"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_new_message_notifications"
    />
```

Comment: @pavlofff пытался делать через boolean и Visibility, проблема в том что я не знаю как отслеживать переключения и где это делать?Не могли бы вы помочь с этим, хотя бы какой то каркас подкинуть.

Comment: @pavlofff познакомился этой статьей, спасибо за ссылку.Но автор не обяснил куда вписывать слушатель?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот примерный каркас, как контролировать изменения в настройках:

Делаете класс настроек:

```
public class AppSettings extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.settings);

        }


    public static class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref);
        }
    }
}
```

разметка settings.xml (путь до фрагмента в атрибуте `android:name` у вас будет свой в зависимости от пакетов):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.example.app.AppSettings$PrefsFragment"
        android:id="@+id/pref_fragment" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Сам XML настроек с чекбоксом *pref.xml* помещаем в папку *res/xml*   (ключ настройки указываем hide_text):

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/tittle_settings">
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:title="@string/show_hidden_text"
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:key="hide_text" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

В меню приложения делаете пункт "Настройки", который будет вызывать активити `AppSettings` (этого нет в коде ответа, так как не относится к вопросу)

Код для контроля за состоянием этой настройки в той активити, в которой используется какая то настройка (в вашем случае, где нужно скрывать\показывать текст):

```
public class SomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{

    private SharedPreferences mPreference;
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        // получаем экземпляр настроек
        mPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        // регистрируем слушатель
        mPreference.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        // Устанавливаем актуальное состояние настройки при создании активити
        boolean isHide = mPreference.getBoolean("hide_text", false);
        textView.setVisibility(isHide ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // отписываемся от слушателя
        mPreference.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    // этот метод сработает, когда в любом ключе настроек произойдут изменения значения
    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
       // проверяем изменилось ли значение нашего ключа hide_text
       if (key.equals("hide_text")) {
            // если изменилось - вносим эти изменения
            boolean isHide = mPreference.getBoolean("hide_text", false);
            textView.setVisibility(isHide ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE); 
       };
    }

}
```

Записывать новые значения или размещать какие то чекбоксы на разметке никуда не нужно, это произойдет автоматически при изменении чекбокса в настройках, а сам чекбокс уже задан в xml-файле *pref.xml*.

Все это будет работать следующим образом. При первом старте у вас будет показываться текст в `TextView` (значение настройки по умолчанию - false)/ Если надо изменить видимость текста, вы вызываете меню приложения и выбираете пункт "Настройки", там переключаете чекбокс и после выхода из настроек и возвата на активити с `TextView`, текст в ней будет скрыт или показан, в зависимости от состояния чекбокса в настройках.

Comment: Спасибо вам, в этом вопросе разобрался.
А как вывести настойки в layout не подскажите?
почему то у меня пустота.

Comment: Делаете switch на layout, и далее в нужной активности делаете обработку нажатия.

Comment: @NasdomlanUrban3p Вот примерно текст мне нужно скрыть в MainActivity, а для настроек я использую Settings.java, обработчик мне нужно добавить в MainActivity ?

Comment: Обработчик делаете в settings.java а в main activity получаете данные из SharedPreference по принципу if(value.equals("text")){ показывает текст } else {скрыли текст} Если я понял вашу задачу

Comment: @NasdomlanUrban3p 
Задача следующая:
Есть активити, на ней написаны так скажем тексты, под текстами написаны переводу на русский язык (это около 10 TextView).Задача заключается в том чтобы при помощи настроек можно было включать/выключать перевод.
Что я сделал:
1. Есть Layout с switch (показать скрыть текст)
2. Есть Settings.class в которой лежит код который предоставил pavlofff
3. Есть MainActivity в которой я написал метод который активируется по запросу с Settings.class.
В итоге у меня не работает, приложение крашится.
Был бы очень признателен за помощь.

Comment: @pavlofff это исчерпывающий ответ)

Comment: @AdamChe пропустил еще применение текущего значения настроек при создании активити, добавил в ответ

Comment: @pavlofff Здравствуйте, не подскажите как реализовать данный код при использовании RecyclerView ?Отдельно вопрос не могу задать так как заморозили.

Comment: при каком использовании RecyclerView?